# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.I don't know how to fix it, can you help?

I download code from https://github.com/alonesuperman/react-native-svg-src

> C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\React\mathero\src\assets\getSvg.js:22
>             Promise.all(files.map(filename => readfile(filename)))
>                               ^
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>     at C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\React\mathero\src\assets\getSvg.js:22:25
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
>
> C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\React\mathero\src\assets>node getSvg.js
> C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\React\mathero\src\assets\getSvg.js:22
>       Promise.all(files.map(filename => readfile(filename)))
>                         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>     at C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\React\mathero\src\assets\getSvg.js:22:25
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
> ```

My error code :

```
//  getSvg.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const svgDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './SVGFOLDER');

function readfile(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(svgDir, filename), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      console.log(data.replace(/<\?xml.*?\?>|<\!--.*?-->|<!DOCTYPE.*?>/g, ''));
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({
        [filename.slice(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'))]: data,
      });
    });
  });
}

function readSvgs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(svgDir, function (err, files) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      Promise.all(files.map(filename => readfile(filename)))
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  });
}

readSvgs().then(data => {
  let svgFile = 'export default ' + JSON.stringify(Object.assign.apply(this, data));
  fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './svgs.js'), svgFile, function (err) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
  })
}).catch(err => {
  throw new Error(err);
});
```

Comment: Test : fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});

Comment: You might try adding an `else` before your `Promise.all`. I might be wrong, but my guess is that your `readdir` is erroring, but the `reject` call doesn't stop code execution and so it's going on to execute the `Promise.all`. That's based on the assumption that `files` will never be null unless there is an error.

Comment: ok i change  './SVGFOLDER'); to sorusvg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i it's okay

const svgDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './SVGFOLDER');

to

const svgDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './sorusvg');

sorusvg is my file :)